# Running a separate firebase instance for dev

Tags: android, firebase

I need to separate  my firebase analytics logs between development/testing and production. I have 2 firebase projects one production and 1 dev. I would like to override the google-services.json file and initialize a difference instance of firebase when on dev. I'm trying to do something like:

```
if(!((MyApplication)getApplication()).isProd()) {
            FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
                    .setApplicationId("mypplicationid")
                    .setApiKey("myKey")
                    .setDatabaseUrl("myurl").build();
            FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this, options);
        }
        else{
            FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this);
        }
```

but the app crashes immediately with FirebaseApp name [DEFAULT] already exists. Is there a way around this besides having 2 google-services.json files and switching them out?

Comment: Your approach pretty much matches what the [Firebase documentation recommends](https://firebase.google.com/docs/configure/#use_multiple_projects_in_your_application), except that you fail to give the `FirebaseApp` a name.

Comment: Adding a name dispelled the crash, but for some reason it's still sending the analytics to the prod firebase account.

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/configure/#reliable-analytics seems relevant to that. I must admit I never tried though, so can't be of much help.

Answer (score 0):

It's preferable to do this by placing your different google-sevices.json files in different directories that correspond to your build flavors for both development and production.  The google services will know which one to use a build time based on which flavor you're building.  [The documentation for the plugin](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/google-services-plugin) has a section that illustrates how you can do this.